# Añadir controles a una vista que ya tiene un signaturepad

Tags: android, c#, .net, xamarin, xaml

Buenas tardes,

estoy haciendo una aplicacion en c# con signaturepad, para Android. Ya tengo el control y funciona, pero ahora quiero grabar la imagen.

En xaml tengo el control del signature pad, y me gustaria saber si puedo agregar, puntualmente un boton de alguna manera, para poder grabawr la imagen de una u otra forma.

El codigo hasta ahora es:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<forms:SignaturePadView
    BackgroundColor="Gray"
    WidthRequest="100"
    HeightRequest="100"
    StrokeColor="White"
    StrokeWidth="3"
    PromptText="Prompt here"
    PromptTextColor="red"
    CaptionText="Caption this"
    CaptionTextColor="Black"

    />
```

Gracias

---

Supongo que tengo problemas con el layout, ya que al añadir un boton, solo me muestra en toda la activitie el boton,

```
<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<forms:SignaturePadView
    BackgroundColor="Gray"
    WidthRequest="100"
    HeightRequest="100"
    StrokeColor="White"
    StrokeWidth="3"
    PromptText="Prompt here"
    PromptTextColor="red"
    CaptionText="Caption this"
    CaptionTextColor="Black"
    x:Name="Pad"

    />

<Button Text="Grabar" />
```

Como dije.. estoy empezando con Xamarin.

Comment: Jordi las actualizaciones a tu pregunta las puedes realizar mediante el botón "editar", no agregues actualizaciones como respuestas. , te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

- Añade un x:Name="Pad" a la definición del SignaturePadView, para poder acceder al elemento visual desde el code behind.
- Añade un botón y define un manejador para el evento Clicked.
- Instala el paquete pclstorage en todos los proyectos, y usa algo como ésto en el manejador de eventos del botón:

  ```
      using (var stream = await Pad.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg))
      {
          var file = await FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage.CreateFileAsync("imagen.jpg",
              CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
          using (var os = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
          {
              await stream.CopyToAsync(os);
          }
      }
  ```

Para tu problema con el botón, es porque un ContentPage puede contener sólo un elemento. Para poder poner más cosas, vas a necesitar un container, como un StackLayout (que apila vertical u horizontalmente), o un Grid:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label ... />
    <forms:SignaturePadView ... />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar y comento. La verdad en esto soy novato.

Comment: No hay problema. Si te sirve, marca la pregunta como respondida.